# How to create a light GUI with TkInter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm writing a program that reads and modifies a binary file which contains infos about some images: but to be able to do that it needs also some informations from the user, let's say the folder where this images are located and few choices.

With a quick research on the web I found that an easy way to create GUIs is Tkinter, and in fact I reached my goal quite fast. 
In particular I used the `tkFileDialog` and `tkMessageBox` modules without the need to call the `mainloop` function , creating and destroying a window whenever I wanted to show something in the screen: I don't think this is the right approach, but it fitted perfectly for my application, since in this way I was able to leave the program as it was before the necessity to "talk" with the user, without the need to refactor it with a purely objected oriented structure as in case of a "real" GUI.

The problem arose when I wanted to improve this interface, and use a *button* widget to give the possibility to choose among three options: in this case the `mainloop` seems mandatory..

So here is the question: does it exist a strategy to communicate with the user without having to put all your functions inside a GUI class and without using a infinite loop? (I think the answer is NO using Tkinter)
What is the best approach in this hybrid situations?

Comment: running an infinite "event loop" is basically how GUI apps run, once it exits the app closes. So no you can't avoid the mainloop, and it doesn't make sense to try.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782425/tkinter-and-gui-programming-methods?rq=1

Comment: @AcidReign: Not necessarily. On Windows, for example, you certainly can do some non-UI work, present a window and run a message loop, let the message loop terminate and do more non-UI work, then present another window and run another message loop… On Windows, often modal dialogs are implemented through nested message loops, too, so it’s really not so cut-and-dry as you suggest.

Comment: Well ok if you want to get pedantic about it (j/k), I concede that you certainly can run a finite/explicit sequence of blocking calls that show dialogs and wait for a response, as you suggest. But that would be a fairly basic/uninteresting GUI

Comment: @ReblochonMasque: thank you for the advice, I almost read all the stackoverflow questions related to how structure your Tkinter project, but not that one. Anyway, I think that in my case the GUI is less important and not the core as in that example.

What it is strange to me (and AcidReign confirms it) is that is out of discussion to have an application whose life is not strictly related with his GUI part, when, my case as example, the GUI part is just a small part of the total task..

Comment: @giubacchio: it is quite common to have a very simple interface and quite complex non-GUI computations. A standard solution is to have a module with your inner-logic functions, then a second GUI module, quite simple, that calls the functions of the first module.

Comment: @EricLevieil: thank you a lot for the tip. I think it is a good idea, but in this way you are forced to start your application with a GUI that asks you what you want to do, and anyway this will break the flow of your program. What if after have writen a big non GUI application (and not completely object oriented), it's needed to have a little interaction with the user?

Comment: Anyway that's not my case, and I think that your solution is the more logical for me, thanks :)
If you, or someone else, think that make sense to write an answer with a short explanation I think it will be useful (and I can accept an answer for my first time :) )

Comment: @giubacchio: didn't have time sooner (perhaps hoping someone will step in?) to put together an answer, but here it is. Comments welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have put together a skeleton. Several remarks:

1. This is a simple case, with only three functions that takes 1 or 2 arguments. However, adapting it to more functions and arguments should be straighforward.
2. I definitely don't advocate short variable names in real programs.
3. Consider using classes a) in base.py if it suits your logic b) in GUI.py as soon as it grows a little
4. Use `grid` optional arguments to have a nice-looking GUI.

To summarize comments above, the goal is to separate the different parts: a first module will contain all the computations, but won't handle user input, a second one will work with command-line user input and rely on the first one for computations and a third will use a graphical interface and rely also on the first one for the computations. You can also add a fourth for tests.
Of course, feel free to modify this pattern as long as you know why.

Comments welcome.

First module:

```
#file base.py
def f1(input1):
    ...
    return res1

def f2(res1, input2):
    ...
    return res2

def f3(res2):
    ...
    return res3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    r1 = f1('directoryPath')
    r2 = f2(r1, 'fileName')
    r3 = f3(r2)
```

Second module:

```
#file commandline.py
from base import *

i1 = input() # in 3.X, raw_input in 2.X
r1 = f1(i1)

i2 = input() # in 3.X, raw_input in 2.X
r2 = f2(r1, i2)
r3 = f3(r2)
```

Third module:

```
#file GUI.py
from base import *
import tkinter as tk # in 3.X, Tkinter in 2.X

def compute():
    i1 = e1.get()
    r1 = f1(i1)

    i2 = e2.get()
    r2 = f2(r1, i2)
    r3 = f3(r2)

    l1.configure(text = r3) #if r3 is a string else str(r3) 

app = tk.Tk()
e1 = tk.Entry(app)
e1.grid()

e2 = tk.Entry(app) 
e2.grid()

b1 = tk.Button(app, text = "Compute", command = compute)
b1.grid()

l1 = tk.Label(app)
l1.grid()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you Eric for your answer! I think I'm missing a crucial point: how the first module can launch the GUI (or the command line part)? It seems that the first one is the "main" one, but I don't understand which is the logic of the others, since they don't contain just class or functions but also some single instructions. Anyway thank you for your time and explanation!

Comment: @giubacchio: the first module cannot launch the others. It may contain almost all the code, but you use one of the others to launch the command-line version or the GUI version.
You may also put all the code in one module, especially if you always want to launch the GUI version.

Comment: What I was looking for is the possibility to have a main structure as the one of your first module, with the capability to call a module like the GUI.py, maybe also more than once, in order to ask few informations to the user. I don't know if this is possible, because in this way more than one mainloop will take place (but not concurrently), and this is generally not allowed.

A way to achieve my goal is to put all the main computation in a function called in the GUI (let's say using a start button), and ask the user when I need some infos. But I don't like this solution so much!